# How to automatically sync Date & Time in windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, time, cmd, synchronization

I would like to write a .bat file that I can schedule with Task Scheduler in Windows.
The script should open the time settings and automatically click the sync option like so:

[image]

So far I was able to open this window by using the following line of code:

```
start ms-settings:dateandtime
```

However I do not know how to click on the Sync now button.

Do you know a smart and elegant way to achieve this task? Feel free to suggest a completely different approach if the final result is the same.

Comment: A batch file cannot interact with GUIs…

Comment: oh ok thanks for the reply! :) Are you aware of any other alternative please?

Comment: Well, [tag:powershell] should be a possible option…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`w32tm /resync`
Must be run by the administrator or else you get a denied message

For more details on other options see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings

```
w32tm /resync
Sending resync command to local computer
The following error occurred: Access is denied. (0x80070005)
```

[image]

On a domain then use

```
w32tm /domain
```

want to use a different server than default ? then replace `time.server.com`

```
w32tm /config /update /manualpeerlist:time.server.com
```

[image]

see https://www.ntppool.org/en/use.html